# Manipulating the equation!

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image]

The question asks to manipulate $f(x,y)=e^{-x^2-y^2}$ this equation to make its graph look like the three shapes in the images I attached.

I got the first one: $e^{(-x^2+y^2)}\cos(x^2+y^2)$.

But I have no idea what to do for second and the third one. Please help me.

Comment: what does it mean "to manipulate equation" ?

Comment: for the second I would take $e^{-(x+y)^2}$

Comment: by multiplication, substitution

for the first one, i multiplied by cos(x^2+y^2) and it looked like a hill (the first image).

Comment: e^-(x+y)^2 does not look like a "hill" at all.

Answer (score 3):

Okey this is the second picture $e^{-(x+y)^2}$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-%28x%2By%29%5E2%29++x+from+-3+to+3%2C+y+from+-3+to+3

And this is the third picture $-e^{-(x^2 - y)^2} $

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-e%5E%28-%28x%5E2+-+y%29%5E2%29+x+from+-5+to+5%2C+y+from+-5+to+5

Comment: Thanks a lot, tom. Idk if i can set the range but I think that's the closest i can do.

Comment: Yes you can set the range. Just change W|A command from "-e^(-(x^2 - y)^2) x from -5 to 5, y from -5 to 5" to "-e^(-(x^2 - y)^2) x from a to b, y from c to d" to plot function on $(a,b)\times(c,d)$

Answer (score 0):

Is the cosine in the exponent?  In case not, [Alpha gives](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20exp%28-%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29%29cos%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29) something that looks like the original function

[image]

If so, [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20exp%28-%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29cos%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29%29) gives something closer to your second target

[image]

Comment: the cosine is not in the exponent but I think multiplying cosine make the graph look more like a hill compared to its original equation.